# Fix for type mismatch error " file to string "

Tags: java

In the below code im list the files from the folders and passing the filepath to the method **loadCSV**. But I am getting type mismatch error here. plz help

```
String Folderfilename= list[i];
```

can saying **"cannot convert file to string"**

```
File foldername = new File(filename);

System.out.println("actual"+foldername);

File[] list = foldername.listFiles();

for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){

    System.out.println("inside for" +list.length);
    String substring = list[i].getName().substring(0, list[i].getName().indexOf("."));

    System.out.println("substring" +substring);

    if(list[i].isFile() && list[i].getName().contains(".csv")) {
        ////////getting mismatch error in the below line
        String Folderfilename= list[i];
        new SCLoad().loadCSV(con,Folderfilename, ImportTable);
        System.out.println("CLASS NAME "+list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `list[i].getName()`? You are doing this in rest of your code.

Comment: And dont forget that your SCLoad wont run if the file extension is Csv, CSV, csV etc. Take a look a code below in my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are looking for files ending with csv. You should probably use a `FileNameFilter`. Here's a snippet

```
File dir = new File("/tmp/");
File[] csvFiles = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith("csv"); //get all csv files
    }
});
//now load these csvFiles using whatever loaders
for (File csvFile :  csvFiles) {
    // I am guessing SCLoad requires a complete path.    
    new SCLoad().loadCSV(con,csvFile.getCanonicalPath(), ImportTable);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply... U r correct loadCSV needs the Complete path . I used your above code. But I am getting nullpointer exception at for (File csvFile :  csvFiles) . Please help

Comment: @123HIS You must pass a directory to `dir`. It should be like `File dir = new File("/path/to/dir/");`

Comment: @123HIS Edit your question and show us the new snippet. Or let me guess. 1. Escape backslashes with 2 backslashes. Add 2 backslashes to the end of your path. Like ` C:\\homepath\\csvFolder\\ `

Comment: Yes, it executed successfully. If i want to pass the one file at a time to the method how to do that? Suppose there are 2 .csv files in a folder. I want to pass one by one to the method .loadCSV  . Please help

Comment: @123HIS You are passing files one by one. You are iterating that array in for loop.

Comment: U mean in this for loop  for (File csvFile :  csvFiles) it will take file one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Here in the line

```
  String Folderfilename= list[i];
```

but  your list is a array of type `File` object.

So you cannot `assign` like that.Type mismatch is there.

May be you need [getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29).

```
 String Folderfilename= list[i].getName();
```

Please add proper checks before using the above line.

Comment: @123HIS You need File name as String ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
File file = list[i];
String Folderfilename= file.getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes in your code:

> list[i].getName();

and

> if( list[i].isDirectory() ) continue; //to avoid exception and to keep looking for csv files.

```
String folderFileName = "";
File foldername = new File(filename);
File[] list = foldername.listFiles();
for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    if( list[i].isDirectory() )
      continue;

    folderFileName = list[i].getName();
    if( folderFileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv") ) {
        System.out.println("csv file: " + folderFileName);
        new SCLoad().loadCSV(con,folderFileName, ImportTable);
    }
}
```